# How to run html file on localhost3000?

Tags: javascript, html

I have all my .js files and html linked to my server file. but when I lunch localhost3000, I get "cannot get/"

I tried anything I though could be helpful but couldn't fix the problem. Anyone knows how to fix it?

I have this for my server side

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at port 3000!'));

app.use(express.static('codefreeze.html'));
```

and I have this for client side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="codefreeze.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codefreeze.css">
    <link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Schoolbell&v1" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>DIARY</title>
</head>
<body onload="Name()">
    <h1>HELLO!</h1>
    <p>Welcome <span id="name"></span></p>
    <p id="date"></p>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = DATE();
    </script>

    <div id="user">

        <label id="lbl1">Passage #1</label><br>
        <textarea id="psg1" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea><br>

    </div>

    <button id="save" onclick="save()">SAVE</button>
    <button id="add" onclick="add()">ADD</button>
    <button id="delete" onclick="del()">DELETE</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I know something I'm doing is wrong but I cannot seem to find what.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  response.sendFile(*your file path*);
});
```

This should work